# Access the retrieved memory in LangChain

Tags: prompt, nlp-question-answering, langchain

Is there any way to access the retrieved vectordb information (imported as `context` in the prompt)?

Here is a sample code snippet I have written for this purpose, but the output is not what I expect:

```
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.prompts.prompt import PromptTemplate
from langchain.vectorstores import Annoy


texts = ["1st line to be embedded......",
         "2nd line to be embedded......",]
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2")
vectordb = Annoy.from_texts(texts=texts, embedding=embeddings)
retriever = vectordb.as_retriever(search_type="similarity", search_kwargs={'k': 1})
prompt_template = """Return these APIs, exactly as provided to you, back to the user. 
                     APIs: {context}
                  """
PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    template=prompt_template, input_variables=['context']
)
chain_type_kwargs = {"prompt": PROMPT}
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=model,  # could be any LLM
    chain_type="stuff",
    retriever=retriever,
    chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs,
)

print(qa.run(query))
```

Basically I want to know how to get the retrieved external dataset (**deterministically**, not using the LLM).

Comment: Did you try passing `return_source_documents = True`?

Comment: @RijoanulHasanShanto Thanks a lot! Yes, just added that. 
But generally, given that it is necessary to pass `context` as an input_variable to the PROMPT_TEMPLATE, I was wondering if there was a way to access that variable inside the prompt.